# How to get the boundaries of currently visible time scale (after panning and zooming)?

Tags: d3.js, zooming, pan

I would like to load in additional data points for the graph only if it scales or translates. Suppose I have a graph for the specific time range (http://codepen.io/jayarjo/pen/gzfyj), now if the user pans or zooms it to a wider range I want to load a wider data corresponding to that range and plot additional data points. I'm not sure how to get the currently visible date range from the D3...?

Comment: The example you've posted doesn't seem to do any panning or zooming. Are you looking for a [brush](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367)?

Comment: You should put the mouse cursor on a dot or date label and then either drag or zoom in with the mousewheel. Isn't it how it works?

Comment: Brush example is great! Tnx. But it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: The zoom behaviour sets `d3.event.translate`, which will give you the currently visible range together with what you set initially.

Comment: But how do I translate these into actual dates (I'm using time scale)? All I need is starting and ending dates.

Comment: You can use your scale's `.invert()` function to map a screen dimension to its input value.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't map to any values that are outside of the initial domain...

Comment: I guess what I would do in this case is to set the input domain to the maximum expected extent and then restrict zooming/panning to that extent.

Comment: Actually... looking at the output of the d3.event.translate I see that it is an offset to a beginning of the domain, so when inverted with scale.invert() whatever the value it will always map to the first value in the domain. So rather than passing translate values, one simply needs to get current inverted value of the 0 and width.

Comment: I'm doing something similar and this helped: D3 changes the scale that you pass in to d3.behavior.zoom() - in your case, set by the `.x(x)` (the y scale is commented out).  You can check the scale's domain and range before and after the zoom and will see that it has been modified by D3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply retrieve inverted values of the beginning and ending points of your scale, which apparently are *0* and *width* of the scale:

```
var startDate = x.invert(0);
var endDate = x.invert(width); // where width is the visible width of the x scale
```

Comment: 4 years later and it helped me.